# Convert the string to the equivalent hex of that string

Tags: vb.net, string, hex

I would like to convert the string that I've inputted to it's equivalent hex.

**For example:**

I have the **string D7** and I would like it to be converted to **hex D7** so that it can be read by the software that can only read hex values.

**bla-bla-bla** = Error, because there's no hex equivalent of it

**aBc** = **ABC** because there's a hex equivalent of it.

**123** = **123** because there's a hex equivalent of it.

**12 AB 3.14** = **Error**, because there's no hex equivalent of it

**3.F1** = **Error**, because there's no hex equivalent of it

Though I'm not sure about that, but I guess that will be the result. As long as there's no hex equivalent of **each** text then it will be error.

Edit: I've tried to convert the C# code of Dmitry, but it is still not working. I'll try it again on Monday

Here's the code

```
Dim source As String = "abc789Def"

Dim Sb As New StringBuilder(source.Length)

For Each c As Char In source
    If ((c >= "0" AndAlso c <= "9") Or (c >= "a" AndAlso c <= "f") Or (c >= "A" AndAlso c <= "F")) Then
        Sb.Append(Char.ToUpper(c))
        Dim result As String = Sb.ToString


        Console.WriteLine("result " & result)
    Else
        Console.Write("Error")
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Could you provide some *more* examples? E.g. what's the expected result for `bla-bla-bla`, `aBc`, `123`, `12 AB` `3.14`, `3.F1`? etc.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Done, see my edit. :) Though I'm not sure. Please ask if you need more clarification sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ability to validate a Hex number is provided by the TryParse method on integer types using the System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber style.

```
Dim inputValue As String = "23"
Dim returnValue As String = Nothing
If ValidateAndFormatHex(inputValue, returnValue) Then
   Console.WriteLine(returnValue)
Else
   Console.WriteLine("Error")
End If
```

---

```
Private Shared Function ValidateAndFormatHex(input As String, ByRef formattedValue As String) As Boolean
   input = input.Trim().ToUpperInvariant
   Dim result As Int32
   Dim parses As Boolean = Int32.TryParse(input, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, result)
   If parses Then formattedValue = input
   Return parses
End Function
```

Comment: This is great, a unique approach to convert string to it's equivalent hex value

Comment: Any idea why `A0 02 50` is working while `A0 05 60 00 65 87` isn't working in your ocde @TnTinMn?

Comment: @CaryBondoc, this technique is parsing the hex string as an Int32 (i.e. 32 bit long integer).  `A0 02 50` = 6 character times (4 bits per character) = 24 bits; which is less than or equal to 32 bits so it can parse.  Your second string is 12 characters long, so it would not fit into a Int32 (hence the parsing fails).  You could change `Int32` to `Int64` to handle up to 16 characters.

Comment: Ah yes, I see. Thank you so much sir. :)

Answer (score 2):

It seems, that you want to have the string to be in *upper case* if *all* the characters in it are in either `['0'..'9']` or `['a'..'f']` or `['A'..'F']` range (C# code):

```
String source = "abc789Def";

if (source.All(c => (c >= '0' && c <= '9') || 
                    (c >= 'a' && c <= 'f') || 
                    (c >= 'A' && c <= 'F'))) {
  String result = source.ToUpper();

  //TODO: put a relevant code here
}
else {
  // error: at least one character can't be converted
}
```

**Edit**: no *Linq* solution:

```
  String source = "abc789Def";

  StringBuilder Sb = new StringBuilder(source.Length);

  foreach (Char c in source)
    if ((c >= '0' && c <= '9') || 
        (c >= 'a' && c <= 'f') || 
        (c >= 'A' && c <= 'F')) 
      Sb.Append(Char.ToUpper(c));
    else {
      // Error: at least one character can't be converted
      return;   
    }

  String result = Sb.ToString();
  // Put relevant code here
```

Comment: Thanks Sir Dmitry, I'll try to convert it to .Net then I can feedback on your answer. Thank you so much. I need to convert it because http://converter.telerik.com/ doesn't seem to convert it right.

Comment: I'm having a hard time on using source.All sir

Comment: You need linq to use his source.

Comment: Thanks. Oh, is there a simpler way to do this? :(

Comment: @Cary Bondoc: you can loop the string *explictly* and create a new one with the help of `StringBuilder`, see my edit.

Comment: Thanks sir. :) I'll try it.