# How to know if the output is "String" or "Hex"?

Tags: vb.net, string, hex, data-integrity

I've asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35520525/convert-the-string-to-the-equivalent-hex-of-that-string/35524733#35524733) that allows me to convert the corresponding string to it's equivalent hex and the second answer seems working.

My question is how do I know if the outputted value is really Hex without using a machine that can only understand Hex?

For example:

**Input:** D7

**Correct Output is:** D7 (This is correct if it is Hex, if it is string then it is not correct)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming there's no limitation on the length of the string to check:

```
Dim _inputStr As String = "D7"
Dim _isCorrectHex As Boolean = Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(_inputStr, "^([0-9a-fA-F]+)$").Success
```