# Send the string to its hex equivalent

Tags: vb.net, serial-port, hex, byte

I would like to send `hex` commands to my device because it can only understand `hex`.

Because of that I manage to create a function that can validate if the users input which is a `string` has a **valid** corresponding `hex`. The question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35520525/convert-the-string-to-the-equivalent-hex-of-that-string).

So, by validating if the `users input` has a corresponding `hex` equivalent I am confident that what my system sends will be read by my device. [By searching](http://vbcity.com/forums/t/106870.aspx?PageIndex=5) I realized that it needs to be converted to bytes, it states

> Use the ASCIIEncoding class to convtert strings to an array of bytes
>   you can transmit.
>
> > **Code:**

```
Dim str as String = "12345678"
Dim bytes() as Byte = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strNumbers)
' Then Send te bytes to the reader
sp.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)
```

> You do not need to covert the values to HEX, in this case HEX is
>   mearly a different way of displaying the same thing.

**My code:**

```
'This is a string with corresponding hex value
Dim msg_cmd as string  = "A0038204D7" 
'Convert it to byte so my device can read it
Dim process_CMD() As Byte = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(msg_cmd) 
'Send it as bytes
ComPort.Write(process_CMD, 0, process_CMD.Length)
```

My Output:

```
41 30 30 33 38 32 30 34 44 37
```

Desired output:

```
A0 03 82 04 D7
```

Comment: Is the only way to talk to the device thru some command line tool?  Isnt there an API where you can send actual bytes?

Comment: There is an API, I'm using [Terminal](https://sites.google.com/site/terminalbpp/) as the receiver to test if what my system sends is really hex or not.

Comment: So you want it to send the hex digits as a string?  If so, which encoding do you want to use for the string?  ASCII?  If you don't want to send it as a string, then you are totally confused, because that's what hex is. Hex is a string representation of a numeric value.

Comment: `it can only understand hex` It wont know the difference between a *byte* value of `16` decimal and `&H10` because they are the same value.

Comment: A number is a number is a number.  It doesn't matter how you *represent* the number, the numeric value of it is the same.  For instance, the numbers 255 in decimal, "Two hundred fifty five" in english, 11111111 in binary, FF in hex, and 两百五十五 in Chinese are all the same number.  They are just written in a different form, but the value is exactly the same.

Comment: Sorry, I'm so confused.I think I really need to spend more time understanding that. That's why I have a feeling that I'm missing something here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To send a specific sequence of bytes, don't send a string--just send the bytes:

```
Dim process_CMD() As Byte = { &HA0, &H03, &H82, &H04, &HD7 }
ComPort.Write(process_CMD, 0, process_CMD.Length)
```

As I mentioned in the comments above, the values are just numeric values.  There is nothing special about hex.  Hex is just another way to represent the same values.  In other words, the code above does exactly the same thing as this:

```
Dim process_CMD() As Byte = { 160, 3, 130, 4, 215 }
ComPort.Write(process_CMD, 0, process_CMD.Length)
```

If you have the hex digits in a string, you can convert a string representation of a hex number to a byte value by using the [appropriate overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7xhf79k(v=vs.110).aspx) of the `Convert.ToByte` method.  However, that only converts one byte at a time, so, first you need to split the string into bytes (two hex digits per byte.  For instance:

```
Dim input As String = "A0038204D7"
Dim bytes As New List(Of Byte)()
For i As Integer = 0 to input.Length Step 2
    bytes.Add(Convert.ToByte(input.SubString(i, 2), 16)
Next
Dim process_CMD() As Byte = bytes.ToArray()
ComPort.Write(process_CMD, 0, process_CMD.Length)
```

However, it would be easier if the string had spaces between the bytes.  Then you could just use the `String.Split` method:

```
Dim input As String = "A0 03 82 04 D7"
Dim hexBytes As String() = input.Split(" "c)
Dim bytes As New List(Of Byte)()
For Each hexByte As String in hexBytes
    bytes.Add(Convert.ToByte(hexByte, 16)
Next
Dim process_CMD() As Byte = bytes.ToArray()
ComPort.Write(process_CMD, 0, process_CMD.Length)
```

Or, more simply:

```
Dim input As String = "A0 03 82 04 D7"
Dim process_CMD() As Byte = input.Split(" "c).Select(Function(x) Convert.ToByte(x, 16)).ToArray()
ComPort.Write(process_CMD, 0, process_CMD.Length)
```

Comment: Oh, yes. That's what I mean. But how do I make `{ &HA0, &H03, &H82, &H04, &HD7 }` depends on the user input?

Comment: Well, that depends on what the values mean and how you intend for the user to enter them.  Are you saying that you just want the user to input the values as a string of hex digits?

Comment: Yes sir. Although there is an API I also want my user to input values for debugging purposes so If a user inputs `A0038204D7` it will be like `Dim process_CMD() As Byte = { 160, 3, 130, 4, 215 }` so my device can received  `A0038204D7`

Comment: Are you really going to make the *user* enter hex?  @CaryBondoc

Comment: @Plutonix well, to be fair, he did say it was purely for debugging purposes :)

Comment: Yes? For debugging purposes only. Because on our documentation all the commands are in hex, so to avoid confusion and conversion I want the user to enter hex.

Comment: @CaryBondoc See my edit.  I added an example of how to do that.

Comment: @StevenDoggart I'm having a problem in this part of code `Dim process_CMD() As Byte = input.ToArray()` it says `value of type char() cannot be converted to byte`. But the last part which is the smallest code that you gave to me works really well. Thanks!

Comment: Oops. You're right. That was a typo on my part. I fixed it. Thanks.

Comment: @Steven Doggart, nice Linq representation.

Comment: @Codexer don't tempt me or I'll throw in a Regex example :)

Comment: @Steven Doggart Haha those are fun as well, heavy on the eyes at times ;)