# Read hex values as is when receiving data from serial

Tags: vb.net, serial-port, hex, receiver

I have a [system capable of sending hex commands as is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35567006/send-the-string-to-its-hex-equivalent), meaning that if I send `A0 02 50 0E` the receiver should receive `A0 02 50 0E` as a hex. It is now working fine, thanks to StackOverlfow.

My problem now is to **receive hex data and convert it as string equivalent of that hex**, it means that if I receive the hex `A0 03 82 04 D7` my system can receive it as string of `A0 03 82 04 D7`.

This is my code: In this example I send a hex value of **`A0 03 82 04 D7`**

```
Dim s As String = ""
s += CStr(ComPort.ReadExisting)
'Just to check the output
Console.WriteLine("s: " & s) 'Outputs "s: ?P" instead of "s: P", this is my first problem

Dim result As String = Nothing
Dim c As Char = Nothing
For Each c In s
   Console.WriteLine("haha: " & c)

   Dim asd As String = Convert.ToUInt16(c).ToString("D2")


   Console.WriteLine("Uint16: " & Convert.ToUInt16(c).ToString("D2"))
   Console.WriteLine("Uint32: " & Convert.ToUInt32(c).ToString("D2"))
   Console.WriteLine("Uint64: " & Convert.ToUInt64(c).ToString("D2"))
   Console.WriteLine("Byte: " & Convert.ToByte(c).ToString("D2"))
   Console.WriteLine("Hex: " & c)

   result &= asd
Next
message_command(msg_usage_enum.serial_received_ascii, result)
Console.WriteLine(result) 'Output is 63028014
```

The result of the loop

```
haha: ?
Uint16: 63
Uint32: 63
Uint64: 63
Byte: 63
Hex: ?
haha: 
Uint16: 02
Uint32: 02
Uint64: 02
Byte: 02
Hex: 
haha: P
Uint16: 80
Uint32: 80
Uint64: 80
Byte: 80
Hex: P
haha: 
Uint16: 14
Uint32: 14
Uint64: 14
Byte: 14
Hex:
```

The last code, which is `Console.WriteLine(result) 'Output is 63028014` is partially correct, `028014` is the correct decimal value the only problem is the first 2 digits which is `63`.

My approach here is to convert it first to decimal value, then from decimal to it's hex equivalent then make it string, but I'am not sure if it will work.

**Edit:** Thanks to Ian I am now having progress.

It's working now, Im just having a problem.Whenever I send `A0038204D7` then my system receives `3F 03 3F 04 3F` which is partially wrong `3F` should be **`A0`**, **`82`** and **`D7`**, while sending `A002500E` my system receives `3F 02 50 0E` which is correct except for **`3F`**. It seems that my system can't process other so he outputs **`3F`**.

This is the latest code I have so far

```
Dim bytes() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(ComPort.ReadExisting())

Dim strs As String() = (From b In bytes
                                        Select b.ToString("X2")).ToArray()
Dim str As String = String.Join(" ", strs)

Console.WriteLine("Result " & str)
```

This is the output in `console.writeline`:

```
Result 3F 02 50 0E
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ToString("X2")` for every byte you receive. You can use `LINQ` to do that, and `String.Join` to combine them back:

```
Dim bytes As Byte() = {&HA0, &H3, &H82, &H4, &HD7}
Dim strs As String() = (From b In bytes
                    Select b.ToString("X2")).ToArray()
Dim str As String = String.Join(" ", strs)
'Your result is in str
```

Comment: I am not familiar with LINQ is it possible to avoid using LINQ?

Comment: Ah yes, thanks! it is working fine. I'm just having a trouble on how can I merge my code `s += ComPort.ReadExisting()` to your code `Dim bytes As Byte() = {&HA0, &H3, &H82, &H4, &HD7}` so every hex data that my system receive will pass through your code

Comment: I see... mine is just showing example of `Byte Array`. In your `For Each c In s` you could possibly use `Convert.ToByte()` rather than `Convert.ToInt16()` and the others. This way, you get each `c` in `s` as `Byte`. But using `Convert.ToInt16()` is also **okay**. The key here is to use `ToString("X2")` actually. LINQ above is just for simplification of `For Each` loop that you have done. Basically you have done the same using `For Each` loop

Comment: Thanks Ian, please see the edit in my question (in the bottom part) I really feel that I am near on making this code work, thank you so much for your assistance.

Comment: @CaryBondoc I just read your updated question: isn't `A002500E` and `A002500E` the same? Also, when you say okay... does it mean you print correctly? I mean, how do you check that you receive: `3F 03 3F 04 3F`? From the debugger? from the `Console.Writeline`?

Comment: My fault, I've edit the bottom part of my question to make it clear. Yeah, I say ok because it outputs partially correct. Please see my edited question

Comment: Do you use Visual Studio? If you do, I am interested to know what do you see in the debugger for `hexByte As String` since you wrote it like this `For Each hexByte As String In s` while `s` itself is of unknown data type to me. What is the data type for `s`? Can you check for me in your debugger?

Comment: Yes, I am using Visual Studio 2015 (vb.net). Please see my edited question sir. Thank you so much.

Comment: By the way I am using `For Each hexByte As Char In s` not string, because it outputs error ` Input string was not in a correct format.` if I use `As String`

Comment: No, no, *don't* print it using `Console.WriteLine` - it is not going to help. Just use your debugger to check what is the data type and the value of `s` and of `hexByte`

Comment: Oh, sorry. Wait sir.

Comment: I'm having a hard time on finding a tutorial on how to use debugger sir. :( It's because I am not aware of it.

Comment: @CaryBondoc some basics debugging: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C0vDKXIq_9A, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eEJ5xKO7c3o

Comment: hexbyte value is `"?"c` while s value is `"?" & ChrW(2) & "P" & ChrW(14)`. Is that what you are looking for sir?

Comment: The values are shown in string type, are they? How about the `data type`? especially `s`. What data type is `s`? You mention that `For Each hexByte As Char In s` gives you error which is interesting. Actually that gives a clue of what could possibly be wrong. Likely, your `s` is of wrong data type to be put in the first place. I wonder what is the return for `ComPort.ReadExisting` in the first place?

Comment: If your system, by `ComPort.ReadExisting` already gives you `Byte()` for example, then you do not need to Convert it to `String` to Convert it back to byte again. Just use it to get `Byte` and convert each `Byte` with `ToString("X2")`

Comment: Oh sorry, my fault what I mean is I'm using `For Each hexByte As Char In s` and it is working fine, if I use `For Each hexByte As String In s` it gives an error. hexbyte dataType is `Char` while `s` dataType is `String`

Comment: Yeah, `ComPort.ReadExisting` should give me `Byte()`. I've tried `Dim bytes As Byte() = ComPort.ReadExisting()` then it says `Value of type String cannot be converted to Byte` that's the reason why I converted it to string.

Comment: Cary, really, - look - I cannot help you more than this... The thing is, the best person to check the problem apart from the conversion which I have shown you is yourself - since you have a full access to the program as well as the debugger while I cannot recreate all possible problems in my PC here. So, please check why the ComPort.ReadExisting reads `string` instead of `Byte()` if you are sure that it has to read `Byte()` actually - you have all the files and IDE needed to do that but I have not. Here, I only try to give you direction.

Comment: Thus, what I show you is that **if** you read `Byte()`, then you should use my method and it should work. As for **why** does it **not** read as `Byte()` **I cannot**  tell why - I do not use `ComPort.ReadExisting` or having access to all your programs. And that's why I suggest you to use your debugger to check on the data type. Please understand this.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your guidance I'll check other possibilities regarding that. Thank you so much sir. You unstuck me in this problem.

Comment: @CaryBondoc no problem, you are welcome. ;) hope you can find out why it is not `Byte()` as you expected. Once you know it, you can use my method.

Comment: Hi Sir, I've got an updated code in my question it's all thanks to you. The only problem that I got is any value larger than `hex 3F` or `decimal 63` doesnt seem to output correctly, I guess it's a whole new question. :) Thanks.

Comment: @CaryBondoc ah, I see... that's why that happen... so no problem with the conversion at all, but you got to check why it cannot output something greater than 6-bit `111111 = 63`. Maybe, that 6-bit itself is a clue. Check it out!